# The bot is joining to room but it doesn't play anything. How can i solve it?

Tags: python, discord, bots

I developed a music bot for Discord. Voice Channel is connecting. Then I want it to find and play the video in the link I want using the !play [url] command. It finds the video from the link, but it gives such a long link that even I encountered an error when I wanted to go to it in my browser. It gives an error in the URL part and I don't know how to solve it. I would be glad if you help.

```
import discord
import youtube_dl
import asyncio

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {client.user}')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!play'):
        video_url = message.content.split(' ')[1]
        voice_channel = message.author.voice.channel

        if voice_channel:
            vc = await voice_channel.connect()

            ydl_opts = {
                'format': 'bestaudio/best',
                'postprocessors': [{
                    'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
                    'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
                    'preferredquality': '192',
                }],
            }

            with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
                info = ydl.extract_info(video_url, download=False)
                url = info['url']
                title = info['title']

            print(url)
            print(title)


            source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(url)
            vc.play(source)
            await message.channel.send(f'Playing: {title}')
        else:
            await message.channel.send('You are not in a voice channel.')

client.run('MTA3MzYwMDg3NTkxNTkxMTIwOQ.G-_ORx.1AK-TL6WvAH_aJRH1wvkGxDxghlJZmo2JCjajQ')
```

And this is the error.
I think error is because of url but I don't know how to solve this.

ERROR

```
2023-02-10 18:11:56 INFO     discord.voice_client Connecting to voice...
2023-02-10 18:11:56 INFO     discord.voice_client Starting voice handshake... (connection attempt 1)
2023-02-10 18:11:56 INFO     discord.voice_client Voice handshake complete. Endpoint found frankfurt1078.discord.media
[youtube] X4CfPG9-FkM: Downloading webpage
https://rr2---sn-u0g3jxaa-5qce.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1676063518&ei=vl7mY_zjFISi-gaU4K6QCQ&ip=212.253.216.191&id=o-AI0qq65XsQ7wWdZdBTthE4v3Gw5I5WXZ-3jEt6YqIqji&itag=140&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=32&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-u0g3jxaa-5qce%2Csn-nv47zn7y&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=2&pcm2cms=yes&pl=19&initcwndbps=751250&vprv=1&mime=audio%2Fmp4&ns=I1SY0RhFsFe80g5OeDudZicL&gir=yes&clen=34515431&dur=2132.659&lmt=1606954057384001&mt=1676041525&fvip=1&keepalive=yes&fexp=24007246&c=WEB&txp=5432434&n=caQSGHXyEwAcOe&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cns%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AOq0QJ8wRQIhAMYXJFytoTl06KgG0CmNeSlce2jz1h9jcME9AsBVaJaIAiAWukU1vWYVCj9B-P0Cgs91BcqqAVwLzEw1rtRyzCYgCg%3D%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpcm2cms%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AG3C_xAwRQIgZ90z7Jg4N-cVhDZ5kqLv_Kp8ch4OJ8zyyGqSz3isk5ECIQDekkPrA0jdBJJMjGayM3S8rZfE5caYg_Msm246ir_zvg%3D%3D
14) Destek ve Hareket Sistemi  2 - Kas Çeşitleri - Özel Ders (11. Sınıf)
2023-02-10 18:12:00 ERROR    discord.client Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Can\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Can\Desktop\Github'a Post Atılacaklar\discord bot.py", line 41, in on_message
    source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(url)
  File "C:\Users\Can\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\player.py", line 289, in __init__
    super().__init__(source, executable=executable, args=args, **subprocess_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Can\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\player.py", line 166, in __init__
    self._process = self._spawn_process(args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Can\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\player.py", line 183, in _spawn_process
    raise ClientException(executable + ' was not found.') from None
discord.errors.ClientException: ffmpeg was not found.
```

Comment: Do you have ffmpeg installed? In the stack trace you have the error: discord.errors.ClientException: ffmpeg was not found.

Comment: Yes i installed it but still the same error

Comment: have you added ffmpeg to the system path?